# docker-compose up vs docker-compose up --build vs docker-compose build --no-cache

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I couldn't figure out what the difference between those.

- `docker-compose up`
- `docker-compose up --build`
- `docker-compose build --no-cache`

Is there any command for `up`without cache?

Answer (score 453):

The following only builds the images, does not start the containers:

- `docker-compose build`

The following builds the images if the images **do not exist** and starts the containers:

- `docker-compose up`

If you add the `--build` option, it is forced to build the images even when not needed:

- `docker-compose up --build`

The following skips the image build process:

- `docker-compose up --no-build`

If the images aren't built beforehand, it fails.

The `--no-cache` option disables the Docker [build cache](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache) in the image creation process. This is used to cache each layer in the *Dockerfile* and to speed up the image creation reusing [layers](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#images-and-layers) (~ Dockerfile lines) previously built for other images that are identical.

Comment: What does `docker-compose up -d` ?

Comment: That starts the containers in detached mode so will not show any output from them in the console and run them in the background.

Comment: Note some options (such as `-d`) for `docker-compose up -d` are not in the documentation for just `docker-compose`. You must look at https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

Comment: is it fair to say that in `docker-compose up --build`, the `--build` part is redundant? If not, then why not please? Thanks.

Comment: @thanks_in_advance `--build` forces the (re-)build of the images. If you omit the flag and the image exists already, it won't get rebuilt.

Comment: so if I run docker-compose up for the very first time on my machine, it will build the image , then run it?

Comment: The `--build` will always rebuild images but only when Dockerfiles are changed.

Answer (score 1):

1. **docker-compose build** when you need to build or rebuild Docker images.
2. **docker-compose up** to start and manage containers based on the images you've built or already have.