# What's the difference between docker-compose -up -d and docker-compose up -build?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm wondering what is the difference between those two commands?

When I'm doing `docker-compose up --build` I got a message:

`php-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)`.

I red that it's because it runs as a foreground process and I need to use `-d` instead.

After running `docker-compuse up -d` I don't get that message.

And the main question is the result are different between those two commands?

Comment: I think you meant `docker-compose up --build`. The one you tried is seen as `docker-compose up -b -u -i -l -d`. Without looking at the docs, I can't tell what that does.

Comment: Yes. I've edited the question.

Comment: Also `docker-compose up --help`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)

- `docker-compose up` builds, (re)creates, starts, and **attaches** to containers for a service.
- `docker-compose up -d` starts the containers **in the background** and leaves them running. (this means that if you want to see the logs of the containers you will have to use `docker-compose logs -f`)
- `docker-compose up --build` **builds** images before starting containers

---

This similar question: [docker-compose up vs docker-compose up --build vs docker-compose build --no-cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39988844/docker-compose-up-vs-docker-compose-up-build-vs-docker-compose-build-no-cach)
 mentions that:

> if you add the `--build` option, it is **forced to build the images even when not needed**.