# How to connect to other container from Dockerfile while docker-compose build

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I try to configure docker compose  for my php project. On deploy I want to update a source code, update composer dependencies and run database migrations.

So I have a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  php:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: php/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:13-alpine"
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB_NAME}
```

Php container builds from the next `Dockerfile`:

```
# Inatall dependensies
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y git libicu-dev postgresql-server-dev-all zip libzip-dev postgresql-client\
&& docker-php-ext-install intl pdo pdo_pgsql zip
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Copy source files
COPY ./app /var/www/my-site

# Update project files
WORKDIR /var/www/my-site
RUN composer install
RUN php ./yii migrate --interactive=0 # This command needs to connect to the database and fails

CMD [ "php-fpm"]
```

When I run `docker-compose build`, I have this error: `could not translate host name "postgres" to address: Name or service not known`.

How can I take access to database container while other is building?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: No. :( I use a hack to solve my problem. I build and run containers without running database migrations. And after it I run migrations inside PHP container by `docker-compose exec`. I wrote a simple bash script for it.

Comment: Sounds good, database needed to be up before you run any migrations. That's what my solution was.

Answer (score 0):

Both `php` and `postgres` need to be on same network and `php` can access `postgres` using `container_name` which is `postgres`. `depends_on` will make sure `postgres` get starts before `php`.

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  php:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: php/Dockerfile
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - test-network

  postgres:
    container_name: 'postgres'
    image: "postgres:13-alpine"
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB_NAME}
    networks:
      - test-network

networks:
  test-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't work. I tried it and took the same error.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, kindly look at this thread it has several solutions.

Comment: How I understand, docker-compose builds containers at first. And only when all of them are ready it runs them with union into a single network. So we can't use network before build will be completed.

Comment: You want to **run** containers as well after building images, right? If you're not sure kindly see this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39988980/6332074)