# docker-compose: nodejs container not communicating with postgres container

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, sequelize.js

I did find a few people with a slightly different setup but with the same issue. So I hope this doesn't feel like a duplicated question.
My setup is pretty simple and straight-forward. I have a container for my node app and a container for my Postgres database. When I run `docker-compose up` and I see the log both containers are up and running. The problem is my node app is not connecting to the database.
I can connect to the database using Postbird and it works as it should.

If I create a docker container only for the database and run the node app directly on my machine everything works fine. So it's not and issue with the DB or the app but with the setup.

Here's a few useful information:

Running a docker just for the DB (connects and works perfectly):

```
> vigna-backend@1.0.0 dev /Users/lucasbittar/Dropbox/Code/vigna/backend
> nodemon src/server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node -r sucrase/register src/server.js`
Initializing database...
Connecting to DB -> vignadb | PORT: 5432
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Connection has been established successfully -> vignadb
```

Running a container for each using docker-compose:

```
Creating network "backend_default" with the default driver
Creating backend_db_1 ... done
Creating backend_app_1 ... done
Attaching to backend_db_1, backend_app_1
db_1   |
db_1   | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1   |
db_1   | 2020-07-24 13:23:32.875 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.1 (Debian 12.1-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1   | 2020-07-24 13:23:32.876 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2020-07-24 13:23:32.876 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1   | 2020-07-24 13:23:32.881 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2020-07-24 13:23:32.955 UTC [27] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-07-23 13:21:09 UTC
db_1   | 2020-07-24 13:23:32.999 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
app_1  |
app_1  | > vigna-backend@1.0.0 dev /usr/app
app_1  | > npx sequelize db:migrate && npx sequelize db:seed:all && nodemon src/server.js
app_1  |
app_1  |
app_1  | Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.5.0, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.3]
app_1  |
app_1  | Loaded configuration file "src/config/database.js".
app_1  |
app_1  | Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.5.0, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.3]
app_1  |
app_1  | Loaded configuration file "src/config/database.js".
app_1  | [nodemon] 2.0.2
app_1  | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
app_1  | [nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
app_1  | [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
app_1  | [nodemon] starting `node -r sucrase/register src/server.js`
app_1  | Initializing database...
app_1  | Connecting to DB -> vignadb | PORT: 5432
```

My database class:

```
class Database {
  constructor() {
    console.log('Initializing database...');
    this.init();
  }

  async init() {
    let retries = 5;
    while (retries) {
      console.log(`Connecting to DB -> ${databaseConfig.database} | PORT: ${databaseConfig.port}`);
      const sequelize = new Sequelize(databaseConfig);
      try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log(`Connection has been established successfully -> ${databaseConfig.database}`);
        models
          .map(model => model.init(sequelize))
          .map( model => model.associate && model.associate(sequelize.models));
        break;
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(`Error: ${err.message}`);
        retries -= 1;
        console.log(`Retries left: ${retries}`);
        // Wait 5 seconds before trying again
        await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 5000));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3333

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services: 
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: vignadb
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"

  app:
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - "3333:3333"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app
    command: npm run dev
```

package.json (scrips only):

```
"scripts": {
  "dev-old": "nodemon src/server.js",
  "dev": "npx sequelize db:migrate && npx sequelize db:seed:all && nodemon src/server.js",
  "build": "sucrase ./src -d ./dist --transforms imports",
  "start": "node dist/server.js"
  },
```

`.env`:

```
# Database
DB_HOST=db
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASS=postgres
DB_NAME=vignadb
DB_PORT=5432
```

database config:

```
require('dotenv/config');

module.exports = {
  dialect: 'postgres',
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
  define: {
    timestamp: true,
    underscored: true,
    underscoredAll: true,
  },
};
```

I know I'm messing up something I just don't know where.
Let me know if I can provide more information.

Thanks!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62958063/6332074) may answer your question.

Comment: Where do you configure the location of the database?  Is it different in your local-development and Docker setups?

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasDilawar thanks but that didn't work. My node app never jumps to the 'Connection has been established successfully' line like it does when I run a separate container.

Comment: @DavidMaze what do you mean?

Comment: He means that you must point your app to the postgres server, somewhere in your configuration. In your app, where do you write the infos you put in POSTGRES_DB, POSTGRES_USER and POSTGRES_PASSWORD ?

Comment: How does sequelize know where to connect?  A log message mentions a `src/config/database.js` file, is that relevant to the question?  These connection details will be different if the application is running directly on the host or in a container, or if the database is on a different host entirely.

Comment: Got it! I have a .env. I'm gonna add the .env file to the question.

Comment: @DavidMaze I've just added those to the question. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @DavidMaze and that's actually another issue. My migrations are not running.

Comment: @DavidMaze can I contact you in private? I can show you the code and everything. I'm really stuck man.

Comment: Where do you have configurations defined in the app?

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasDilawar I just updated the post with more info about the config. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Let's chat in private. We need more entries here to get chat window.

Comment: Did you try using Network?

Comment: I don't see any network in your `docker-compose`.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasDilawar I did try but I removed since it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You should put your 2 containers in the same network https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

And call your db service inside your nodejs connexion string.

Something like: `postgres://db:5432/vignadb`

Comment: The two containers are already in the same (`default`) network; you don't need to manually configure this.

Comment: @MichéeLengronne I did try that before but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: To put in the same network is not enough, you must configure your app with the postgres connexion infos (in my example `postgres://db:5432/vignadb`)