# Docker: Node server is not running after start the server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a `Dockerfile` and a `docker-compose.yml` file.
If I execute `docker-compose up`, it returns:

```
    Creating network "demoapi_webnet" with the default driver
    Creating demoapi_web_1 ... done
    Creating d2c_postgres  ... done
    Attaching to demoapi_web_1, d2c_postgres
...
d2c_postgres | 2020-07-28 00:47:48.772 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

But my node server is not starting.
These are my docker configuration files:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12.13-alpine As development
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm install
COPY dist .
COPY wait-for-it.sh .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        networks: 
            - webnet
        container_name: "d2c_postgres"
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 010203
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_DB: demo
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
    web:
        image: nest-app
        ports: 
            - "3000:3000"
        networks:
            - webnet
        environment: 
            DB_HOST: db
        command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "npm", "run", "start"]
networks:
    webnet:
```

My only clue is this line:
env: can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory

I can stablish a connection to pgadmin/postgres with that configuration, but the `node` server is not starting. What am I doing wrong and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait-for-it is base on **bash** and it's not compatible with alpine as alpine is base on `ash` or `sh` that is why you are seeing `can't execute 'bash': No such file or directory`. You can look into the open issue for alpine support.

[Can you make an /bin/sh version for use with alpine linux](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it/issues/18)

For alpine, you can use [wait-for](https://github.com/Eficode/wait-for)

> `./wait-for` is a script designed to synchronize services like docker containers. It is **sh and alpine compatible**.

```
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.4

  backend:
    build: backend
    command: sh -c './wait-for db:5432 -- npm start'
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 0):

After big research, I found a similar issue here:
[docker-compose: nodejs container not communicating with Postgres container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63074581/docker-compose-nodejs-container-not-communicating-with-postgres-container)

For some reason `wait for it` wasn't working (not sure if is a windows issue), that `sh` file is not mandatory to wait until database start, you can use `depends_on` to indicate that the server should start after a specified service:

```
version: '3'
services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        networks: 
            - webnet
        container_name: "node_postgres"
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 010203
            POSTGRES_USER: postgres
            POSTGRES_DB: demo
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
    web:
        image: nest-app
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports: 
            - "3000:3000"
        networks:
            - webnet
        environment: 
            DB_HOST: db
        command: ["npm", "run", "start"]
networks:
    webnet:
```