# Docker containers crashed: /bin/sh: 1: [uvicorn,: not found

Tags: python, docker, fastapi

I am new to Docker and trying to Dockerize my FastAPI application.
First I created a Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.9

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

Then ran the following command:

```
docker build -t fastapi .
```

The command ran successfully.

After that I created the following docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services: 
  api:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
         ./.env
```

Then ran the following command:

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Ran successfully:

```
    Network fastapi_default  Created                              0.7s 
 - Container fastapi_api_1  Started
```

Then to check if its running properly I ran the following command:

```
docker ps -a
```

And it showed that Container exited few seconds after it was created.

Then I ran this command:

```
docker logs fastapi_api_1
```

And it says:

```
/bin/sh: 1: [uvicorn,: not found
```

Not sure what is the reason. Tried some solutions that I found online but nothing worked out. I do have uvicorn in my requirements.txt file.

Help will be appriciated. Please let me know if additional information is required.

Comment: That error almost always means there's something wrong with the JSON-array syntax in the `CMD`.  What you show in the question seems right; double-check that you have straight double quotes around the individual words, and ordinary spaces between them (not single quotes, Unicode "curly" quotes, or different Unicode spaces).

Comment: do a `docker run myimage uvicorn` once to see if its available. Just to rule out that its not an issue with CMD syntax. The CMD looks fine to me.

Answer (score 5):

Note: You don't need to do `docker build -t fastapi .` manually. Docker-compose will do it for you (because you set `build: .`) But! You must run `up` command with `--build` parameter (`docker-compose up --build`) to [force rebuild image even if it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39988980/13946204).

And about your problem:

Here is a [very good article](https://goinbigdata.com/docker-run-vs-cmd-vs-entrypoint/) (and [one more](https://www.ctl.io/developers/blog/post/dockerfile-entrypoint-vs-cmd/)) about `RUN`, `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`

Here is three forms for `CMD`:

> - CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] (exec form, preferred)
> - CMD ["param1","param2"] (sets additional default parameters for ENTRYPOINT in exec form)
> - CMD command param1 param2 (shell form)

According error, looks like Docker interpreting `CMD` as a shell form or additional parameters for default `ENTRYPOINT`

Actually still not sure why it happens, but changing `CMD` to

```
CMD uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
```

or

```
ENTRYPOINT ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

should solve your problem

Also it will be better to use full path to `uvicorn` executable (`/usr/bin/uvicorn` or where it installed by default?). It is just my opinion but, that is may be a reason why `CMD` is interpreted as parameters instead of command.

PS In addition here is note from [docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> Note
> The exec form is parsed as a JSON array, which means that you must use double-quotes (“) around words not single-quotes (‘).

So `exec form` syntax must meet the conditions of JSON syntax.

Comment: Yeah definitely need to use the full path to uvicorn based on this error

Comment: @AlexW Actually I don't understand why `uvicorn` interpreted as `[uvicorn,` but not `uvicorn` even if it is just a parameter for original `ENTRYPOINT`...

Comment: tried everything mentioned above but nothing worked out.

Comment: Whats weird is that even when changed `CMD` from:

`CMD [ "uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000" ]`

to

`CMD uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000`

it still shows the same error:

`/bin/sh: 1: [uvicorn,: not found`

even though there is no square bracket or comma.

Comment: Entrypoint is probably not better.

Comment: This solution worked for me, by adding --build. Working command is: sudo docker compose up -d --build

Answer (score 3):

Check your `CMD` in Dockerfile. Please give as

```
CMD python3 -m uvicorn app:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80
```

The docs says you can use like this in CMD rather than `CMD ["uvicorn", ....]`

https://docker-fastapi-projects.readthedocs.io/en/latest/uvicorn.html

Hope this works for you.

Comment: This solution is nice if you have a multi-stage Dockerfile where build context is not the same as run context, so shell wouldn't know uvicorn but python would thanks to pythonpath.
Just take care exec form vs shell form if you have a variable like $PORT

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with a *Dockerfile* in my *docker-compose* environment containing

```
COPY ./requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install uvicorn==0.20.0
CMD ["uvicorn", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "6000", "app:app"]
```

So I don't need an extra `command:`line in my docker-compose.yml
It turned out that if you install *uvicorn* in your *requirements.txt*, as I like to do for testing purposes
then it gets installed locally, and
`RUN pip install uvicorn==0.20.0` is skipped, which means,
there is no `/usr/bin/uvicorn` 'executable' available, just somewhere in *site-packages* and `CMD` will fail.
So, if you use *uvicorn* in your *requirements.txt*, and in *Dockerfile* as well, you can maybe
force the reinstallation

```
RUN pip install --ignore-installed uvicorn==0.20.0
```

in the Dockerfile,
or set the PATH to find it somewhere in the guts of python,
or - what I find is a better solution to keep the image size small -
is to remove *uvicorn* from *requirements.txt*...

Answer (score -1):

So, basically there was something wrong with the docker. I had created mulitple images. I removed all of them and ran the same commands again and it worked. I don't know the exact reason but its working now.

What I think was happening is that instead of deleting the old images and creating new one. I was just doing

```
docker-compose down
```

and then

```
docker-compose up -t
```

I think that command was not taking the changes into consideration.

then i ran:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

and I think that created a new image and it worked.

Then I noticed that there were atleast 10 images created. I deleted all of them and ran the same commands:

```
docker build .
docker-compose up -t
```

and it worked fine again.

So basically instead of using creating new image it was using the old one which was not created correctly:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

In short you should use `docker-compose up --build` whenever you make changes in your dockerfile or docker-compose.yml instead of `docker-compose up -t`

It might be confusing but I am also very new to Docker.

Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yes `docker-compose down` [don't delete](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/down/) image by default (you need to set `--rmi`) and `docker-compose up` don't [rebuild image if it already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39988980/13946204). So you reused same image. Sorry, I didn't mention it when said `You don't need to do docker build -t fastapi . manually`

Comment: No problem. I guess thats how we learn. I am stuck on another step though. Take a look if you can help lol.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70298161/docker-error-relation-users-does-not-exist-at-character-13